# Is this prepositional phrase a 'predicative adjunct'?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, non-restrictive, adjuncts

> The class was composed of thirty students, **including Jonathan and Kelly**.

In this sentence, the prepositional phrase 'including Jonathan and Kelly' is a non-restrictive element in the clause structure (a supplementary adjunct). It does not modify 'thirty students' but provides additional information about them.

Can we call this a predicative adjunct? I am familiar with the concept of 'supplementary adjectives', which are said to be classified this way (see [this forum discussion](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=23884)). They, too, provide information about a noun phrase.

Comment: You can call it anything you want. "Predicative adjunct" is a nice, meaningless phrase that will work as a name until a good description gets made and accepted. And I would call _including Jonathan and Kelly_ a participial phrase, since _including_ is a participle. To the extent it's related to a relative clause, the antecedent would be the count expressed in _thirty students_, since the number included Jonathan and Kelly.

Comment: There are two schools of thought here: (1) "Including" is a preposition, so "including Jonathan and Kelly" is a preposition phrase functioning as an adjunct. (2) "Including" is reanalysed as a marginal member of the coordinator category, so it would be an NP functioning as second coordinate in the coordination "thirty students, including Jonathan and Kelly". I wouldn't call it a predicative adjunct since it has no predicand.

Comment: Incidentally, the term 'predicative adjunct' applies to such expressions as _**A proud teetotaller**, John stuck to water while the others drank champagne_ (NP) / _**In a bad temper**, as usual, John walked on ahead of the main party_ (PP) / _She ran through another set of rooms, **breathless**, searching for a way out_ (AdjP).

Comment: There are far more than two schools of thought. As I said, "predicative adjunct' can be applied to anything you like.

Comment: Boy, I really do not get it. How can: A proud teetotaller, John [etc] OR John, a proud teetoller [etc] be anything other than an apposition? And isn't a predicate adjunct part of a predicate?? Isn't John the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The class was composed of thirty students, including Jonathan and*
> *Kelly*.

No, it's not a predicative adjunct since it doesn't relate to a predicand. Compare, for example, *Unwilling to accept these terms, Max resigned*, where the AdjP "unwilling to accept these terms" is an adjunct in clause structure and it is also predicative in that it relates to a predicand, i.e. "Max".

In your example, the expression *including Jonathan and Kelly* does not relate to a predicand. It does not provide ascriptive information about "the class" or "thirty students".

The received wisdom seems to allow for two possible interpretations:

1. "Including" is a preposition, so "including Jonathan and Kelly" is simply a preposition phrase functioning as an adjunct, probably a supplementary one.
2. "Including" is reanalysed as a marginal member of the coordinator category, so it would be an NP functioning as second coordinate in the NP coordination "thirty students, including Jonathan and Kelly". This interpretation is weakened by the fact that it can be fronted, as in *Including Jonathan and Kelly, the class was composed of thirty students.*

Comment: Is this all CGEL, or do the two analyses you offer have different sources?

Comment: Does the same analysis hold when you interpose the *including * between subject and verb? *Thirty students, **including Jonathan and Kelly,** composed the class.* Here the *including * phrase seems to function like *along with *, *as well as *, and *not to mention * all do. Does it? And does this construction differ grammatically from *Two students, (namely) Jonathan and Kelly, led the class yesterday because the professor was ill*  is?  Does dropping *namely* even matter for that analysis?

Comment: @tchrist 2. holds in your first example, where the _including_ phrase would then be part of the subject. "As well as" and "not to mention" function like coordinators. In your last example, "(namely) J&K" is undoubtedly a supplementary appositive NP, where "namely" is optional.

Comment: Ok good, that makes sense to me.

Comment: +1 (I'm sure some readers won't be familiar with *predicand*. Might be useful to give a quick explanation in brackets on first usage?)

Comment: I've only just heard about the concept of the 'predicand' now. I need to do some extra reading.

Comment: @ MJ Ada A predicand is what a predicative complement or adjunct relates to (usually a noun phrase): In _Sue seems capable_ and _I consider Sue capable_  Sue is the predicand, i..e. one who is thought capable. In _[Unwilling to accept these terms], Max resigned_ the adjective phrase "unwilling to accept these terms" is a predicative adjunct predicated of Max, the predicand. [link](https://www.yourdictionary.com/predicand)

Comment: @BillJ It might be useful for readers if you put a short explanation in your post :)

Answer (score 0):

> The class was composed of thirty students, including Jonathan and Kelly.

*including Jonathan and Kelly* is a participle phrase.

It is an adverbial free modifier, i.e. it does not modify the specific verb "composed", rather it modifies the entire main clause: *The class was composed of thirty students*

The positioning is also quite free as the phrase is in parentheses:

Including Jonathan and Kelly, the class was composed of thirty students.

The class, including Jonathan and Kelly, was composed of thirty students.

The class was composed, including Jonathan and Kelly, of thirty students.

The class was composed of thirty students, including Jonathan and Kelly.

for further information see [ThoughCo](https://Free%20modifiers%20can%20come%20in%20several%20forms.%20There%20is%20no%20single%20format%20or%20construction%20required,%20but%20many%20of%20them%20will%20use%20the%20present%20participle%20form%20of%20a%20verb.%20Most%20of%20the%20time,%20these%20phrases%20will%20give%20more%20information%20about%20the%20subject,%20further%20developing%20it%20or%20adding%20specificity.%20A%20free%20modifier%20phrase%20is%20not%20necessary%20to%20the%20sentence%20(the%20main%20clause%20will%20still%20be%20grammatically%20and%20logically%20sound%20without%20it),%20but%20enhances%20it%20with%20further%20ideas%20or%20details.):

> Free modifiers can come in several forms. There is no single format or construction required, **but many of them will use the present participle form of a verb**. Most of the time, these phrases will give more information about the subject, further developing it or adding specificity. A free modifier phrase is not necessary to the sentence (the main clause will still be grammatically and logically sound without it), but enhances it with further ideas or details.

Comment: How can "including Jonathan and Kelly" possibly be a participle phrase when "including" is not even a verb here?

Comment: @BillJ including" is not even a verb. ! The semantics give it away: *The class was composed of thirty students, **and I am including** Jonathan and Kelly.*

Comment: It's a preposition, as dictionaries confirm: see [link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/including?q=including) [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/including)

Comment: I remain unimpressed by what seems to be a fudge and miscategorisation. We are talking about the function here. How would one differential "and I am including Jonathan and Kelly"? These participle phrases are invariably parenthetical and simple ellipsis of a larger clause - as in reduced relative clauses.

Comment: So **all** dictionaries miscategorise it? I don't think so. There are no grounds for considering it to be a verb here. FYI the preposition "including" arises through the conversion of the non-tensed form. It's analysed as a prep because there is no understood subject. Others preps that are homonymous with a participle include "excepting", "barring", "excluding" and "given". There are quite a few others.

Comment: @BillJ An ostrich with one leg (we may say "an ellipsed leg") is still an ostrich. You know that English loves ellipsis. *"It's analysed as a prep because there is no understood subject."* I think most people will be able to insert a subject without much difficulty.

Comment: If you can come up with a plausible subject in the OP's example, you're a better man than I am, Gunga Din! There's no ellipsis. "Including" is a prep as the grammars and the dictionaries tell us.

Comment: @BillJ *If you can come up with a plausible subject in the OP's example* - I have done: **and I am including Jonathan and Kelly"** (or "and that is including J &K")

Comment: @BillJ - Where are these "prepositions" in French and German? (I hold myself hostage to fortune here - take advantage...)